# Number of training samples for each class using ImageDataGenerator with validation_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Using Keras, I have images in `X` and labels in `Y`. Then I do:

```
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split = 0.25)

 train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X, Y, subset = 'training')
```

My question is: when `train_generator` is used within `fit_generator` of a model, how many samples from each class are actually presented as training samples?

For example, if I have 1000 (x, y) pairs for 3 classes: 500 for class A, 300 for class B and 200 for class C, how many samples from class A, B and C do `fit_generator` really see as training samples?  Or all we can do is: 500*(1.0 - 0.25) and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we inspect [the relevant part of the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/5e3486c348ec4d713e9a7af0ee570d32cb552e60/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1627-L1647), we would realize that the last `validation_split * num_samples` samples in the `X` (and `y`) will be used for the validation and the others will be used for training:

```
split_idx = int(len(x) * image_data_generator._validation_split)

# ...
if subset == 'validation':
    x = x[:split_idx]
    x_misc = [np.asarray(xx[:split_idx]) for xx in x_misc]
    if y is not None:
        y = y[:split_idx]
else:
    x = x[split_idx:]
    x_misc = [np.asarray(xx[split_idx:]) for xx in x_misc]
    if y is not None:
        y = y[split_idx:]
```

So it is your responsibility if you want to make sure the proportion of classes is the same in both training and validation subsets (i.e. Keras does not guarantee that when using this functionality). The only thing that Keras [verifies](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/5e3486c348ec4d713e9a7af0ee570d32cb552e60/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1629) is that at least one sample from each class is included in both training and validation subsets:

```
if not np.array_equal(
        np.unique(y[:split_idx]),
        np.unique(y[split_idx:])):
    raise ValueError('Training and validation subsets '
                     'have different number of classes after '
                     'the split. If your numpy arrays are '
                     'sorted by the label, you might want '
                     'to shuffle them.')
```

---

So the solution to have a stratified split (i.e. preserving the porportion of samples for each class in training and validation splits) is to use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) with `stratify` argument set:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

val_split = 0.25
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=val_split, stratify=y)

X = np.concatenate((X_train, X_val))
y = np.concatenate((y_train, y_val))
```

Now you can pass `validation_split=val_split` to `ImageDataGenerator` and it is guaranteed that the proportion of classes is the same in both training and validation subsets.

Comment: Crystal clear - thank you so much!  Is there a trick to zoom onto the corresponding source code other than spending time and gaining familiarity with the package?  Used to be an on-the-surface, documentation-only user :-)

Comment: @willz Well, Keras source code is not that hard to inspect since it does not have so much files. You just need to go to the relevant file, which is very easy to find based on the modules you are using, and read the source code. So no trick, at least for me :)